# Express.js Router "catchall" load index with any url param

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have a basic project set up with server.js in my root with this code:

`app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));`

Additionally I have a public folder with index.html, styles and scripts folder in that dir root.

I'd like my web application to send users to index.html regardless of any url paramaters they might have. For example: If a user tries to go to localhost:8888/notarealpage it still loads index.html (without a redirect) so I can still reference the 'notarealpage' in the location.href property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});
```

This way, it will send your index.html no matter the URL.

Please notice you might have to fine tune the `sendFile` parameter.

Comment: Says path is not defined.

Comment: Then define it. `var path = require('path');`. It's built in to nodejs

Comment: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/public'
   at Error (native)

Comment: As I said, you might have to fine tune that. Simple use `console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'))` before the `sendFile` and verify that the path resolved is correct.

Comment: and make sure, you define this rule at the end of all rules, else, it will tries to load this file , even for `js` or `css`.

Comment: I got it working with:
```app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile((__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});```

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile((__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});
```

to the end of my routes in server.js did the trick.

Comment: OP, Please give credit to the original answer by @Gilad Artzi.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37803730/923426